# push 1 less than %ecx to stack

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, att

I am trying the push onto the stack a value which is `one less than %ecx`.

So I tried this instruction for that:

```
pushl $(%ecx - 1)
```

However I get the below error from `as`.

```
fact.s: Assembler messages:
fact.s:49: Error: register value used as expression
```

As a workaround I did the following:

```
movl %ecx, %edx
subl $1, %edx
pushl %edx
```

But is there there a way to do it without using extra registers (`%edx` in this case) ? And in one instruction ?

Comment: The x86 architecture is not particularly efficient, flexible, or orthogonal.  Other CPUs would make meeting some of those constraints easier, but not all of them.  Some programming conventions for CPUs with lots of registers tend to reserve a register to always hold the constant 1 (one) to optimize this type of operation.  (The [CDC Cyber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_Cyber) comes to mind.)

Comment: If you can use an extra reg, a shorter workaround is `lea -1(%ecx), %edx  / push %edx`.  Otherwise, you need to have a value fully computed in a register as input to other instructions.  Immediate values have to be assemble-time constants (which is why you get that error from the assembler).

Answer (score 5):

Without extra registers? Sure. dec/push/inc. One instruction? No.

```
decl  %ecx
pushl %ecx
incl  %ecx
```

Answer (score 5):

Two instructions:

```
pushl %ecx
subl $1, (%esp)      # or decl (%esp)
```